# Why there is no DI for Ilogger in web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I wanna know (want to know) why we can use `ILogger` in the *controller*  without adding the *dependency injection* (DI) for it in `ConfigureService` ?

```
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {    
        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

        public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger,
```

Hope my question is clear.

Comment: Because ASP.NET Core adds it for you automatically.

Comment: There's an [AddLogging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.loggingservicecollectionextensions.addlogging) extension method that configured the logging system with the built-in configuration system (and registers `ILogger<T>`). Under some configurations, this method is called automatically by the framework.

Answer (score 1):

please add below in start up file:

```
private void CreateServiceProvider()
{
    services.AddLogging();//<--HERE
}
```